# How to diagnose long-running PHP curl requests

Tags: php, apache, curl, logging, heroku

Our PHP web app makes a series of curl requests to APIs in response to certain requests. We're debugging a problem where the request occasionally times out after 30 seconds with a 503 response code... we're pretty sure it's because one (or two) of the curl requests is taking too long.

In an effort to diagnose which curl requests are the problem, we'd like to log or track the individual requests. We're hosting the app on a Heroku Cedar instance with the Logentries add-on and we also use New Relic, but neither tools seem to offer an option to log/track the individual `curl`s. How do we do this?

I know we could set variables with timestamps and log them manually... but suspect we'd be "reinventing the wheel." What's the best way to do this, preferably without messing with our code base.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need xdebug and code modifications to diagnose it. I guess you don't have to change much on the code but set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);  //set it to 0 for infinity
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds, increase that
```

also don't forget to enlarge time execution of php script self:

```
`set_time_limit(0);//` to infinity for example
```

Comment: Where doees xdebug factor into your example above? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: That's if you decided to use xdebug to diagnose curl. for example in curl you can set curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'XDEBUG_SESSION=1');

Comment: Rereading your answer... can you explain a bit what/why the two `curl_setopt`s are for? Are they for fixing the connection timeout? Or for debugging purposes? I'd prefer not to increase the tolerances to allow slow requests. Rather I'd like to identify which calls are slowing everything down (and possibly remove them). Does that make sense?